# Azure database partitioning with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have application deployments which use the same database schema and share some of the data. The application uses data access with Entity Framework. I access the data in database by creating an instance of `MyEntities` and operating on it:

```
db = new MyEntities();
List<Things> AvailableThings = db.Things.Where(t => t.Availability).ToList();
```

Take as an example two applications (A1, A2) and three databases (D0, D1, D2) such that:

For both A1 and A2, D0 is read-only.

When I create `new MyEntities()` in A1, it will combine data from D0 and D1. When I execute `MyEntities.SaveChanges()` in A1 it will write new entries to D1 and refuse to commit changes to entries in D0.

When I create `new MyEntities()` in A2, it will combine data from D0 and D2. When I execute `MyEntities.SaveChanges()` in A2 it will write new entries to D2 and refuse to commit changes to entries in D0.

Entries in D1 and D2 might have Foreign Keys that refer to entries in D0.

Goal: to centralize the shared data between all applications which use it.